# Docker running the containers and modifying environment settings

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose

Set up is on a Ubuntu  18.10 x64

Trying to set up a set up a Laravel, Nginx, and MySQL droplet with Docker Compose, with this tutorial [docker tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-laravel-nginx-and-mysql-with-docker-compose) and I get all the way to step 8 in the tutorial where it asks me to run this command

```
$ docker-compose exec app nano .env
```

and it gives me an error of

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"nano\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

I have spent the better half of a day looking on line for any kind of help or clues on what i could have done wrong. any info I can give you please let me know.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well... This error throws because there is no 'nano' editor installed in this container. If you're familiar with vim you can use it like this:

```
docker-compose exec app vim .env
```

You also can enter to the container's shell and then install nano to use it like that:

```
docker-compose exec app /bin/sh
```

and then in container install nano editor. Installation command will depends on the OS. For example, if container is based on ubuntu youll need to type:

```
apt-get install nano
```

of if it's based on alpine-linux:

```
apk add nano
```

and so on... You can google it easily ;)
You can check which OS it is using next command:

```
lsb_release -a
```

Hope it helps ya

Comment: when I try and install nano it tells me `E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?`

Comment: @whisk try to run the same command with sudo (sudo apt-get install nano, for example)

Comment: I tried that and it yelled at me `/bin/sh: 2: sudo: not found`. I was able to get the file open with vim I just didnt know how to edit it.

Comment: @whisk well, I can recommend you [this](https://www.openvim.com) great vim interactive course. It spend not a lot of time, some about 15-20 minutes but gonna be really useful, cause vi by default preinstalled (and sometimes only) editor in most Linux distributions. Alternatively you can try to use su command to reenter as superuser and then try to install nano

Answer (score 5):

you can go inside container with specific user and this case you must have root :

```
docker exec --user="root" -it <container_name> /bin/bash
```

then :

```
apt-get install nano
```